# Reduce space between y axis and cathegories in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made the graph below with ggplot. I would like to reduce the distance between the y axis and the first category (a). Which function should I use?  Thanks! :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), group = 1:10)
data <- melt(data, id = "group")

ggplot(data, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = group, color = as.factor(group))) + geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_minimal() + theme(axis.line = element_line(), panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: it would help if you could post your current code

Comment: @greysaff now there is code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3),
                 y = rnorm(9),
                 z = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z, group = z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

We can reduce the space between the extreme points and the panel edges by adjusting the `expand` argument in a scale function:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z, group = z)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0.1))
```

[image]

Setting `expand = c(0,0)` completely removes the space. The first argument is a relative number, the second an absolute; so in the example above we set the expand to 0.1 x-axis units.